# What is the correct way to implement OnCreate/OnResume in regards to saving intents etc

Tags: android, xamarin, implementation, oncreate

I have a pretty large android application, all works well, unless when i get out of my application (onpause?) and when i try to get into my (not closed) application later.

So when i open it to continue where i started it throws a nullpointer exception or an inflate exception.

So where should i implement what?

OnCreate: only inflate layout elements?

OnStart: Assign values to inflated elements?

OnResume: do the same as in OnStart?

OnPause: should i save the value of my intent?

For example, one activity is all based on a certain ID that it will give in it's intent. At on create, he looks for his intent, and then sets the value of the intent and uses that to make some calls.

When i start the application at some later point, will he call the OnCreate (if the application window is not in RAM anymore?)? and when he does will OnCreate still have the intent (with values in there) with which it was called with?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of documentation and training about this on the [Android Developer website](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)